# How do I change the color of a button so that it changes to another color when its clicked using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the color of a button whenever it's clicked to show that that is the current page being viewed.  I tried to code using jQuery but its not changing color when I click the button.  Could someone help me with the jQuery code I need?  I'm not well versed with jQuery syntax.

I tried css with jQuery, but button won't change color.

PHP:

```
$output .= '<div id="myDIV" style="text-align:center;">';
for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
  $output .= "<button class='pagination_link btn' id='".$i."'><a href='#'>".$i."</a></button>";
}
$output .= '</div>';
echo $output;
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
load_data();
function load_data(page)
{
    $.ajax({
         url:'pagination.php',
         method:'POST',
         data:{page:page},
         success:function(data) {
               $('#pagination_data').html(data);
         }
     });
}
$(document).on('click','.pagination_link', function() {
        var page = $(this).attr("id");
        load_data(page);
 });
```

});

How do I fix this so the button changes color and not get removed when the ajax method reloads the data onto the page?
I want the button to change color to show that is the current page being viewed.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change font color when clicking on menu with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955440/change-font-color-when-clicking-on-menu-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to the button when it is clicked, and make sure that your css file has a definition for it.  For example, imagine class "bgGreen" in css:

```
.bgGreen{background-color:green;}
```

Assuming you have multiple buttons, you might first want to remove that class from all other `.pagination_link` buttons before adding it to the button just clicked:

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function() {
    $('.pagination_link').removeClass('bgGreen'); //First remove from all buttons
    $(this).addClass('bgGreen'); //Then add it to THIS button
    var page = $(this).attr("id");
    load_data(page); 
});
```

#### DEMO:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(){
   $('.pagination_link').removeClass('bgDarkCyan');
   $(this).addClass('bgDarkCyan');
});
```

```css
.bgDarkCyan{background:darkcyan;color:white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" class="pagination_link">Button One</button>
<button id="btn2" class="pagination_link">Button Two</button>
<button id="btn3" class="pagination_link">Button Three</button>
```

---

If the page reloads, then you need to take a different approach. The big-picture idea is to check the current page name (url) and match that to one of the button IDs or classes. *This might involve a bit of string manipulation, or you can intentionally make your `.php` page names match your ID or class names, which makes the job much easier.*

You can either do this in PHP at the top of the page, or in javascript/jQuery after the page has loaded.

[Here's a PHP example that looks simple and effective](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45237182/1447509)

[Here's a javascript/jQuery example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037396/how-to-add-dynamic-active-class-on-selected-page)

Comment: the button just changes color on click, then ajax method reloads the pagination links; thus removing the color.  How could I find and set the active page link after the ajax loads the page?

Answer (score 1):

In your click event, you can do something like this.

```js
$('.pagination_link').css({'background': ''}); // this removes the new color from all buttons
$(this).css({'background': '#00F'}); // this changes the background of the clicked button
```

Comment: This will work just fine, but adding a class is probably the better way to go. +1 though for the example and for the comments in the code.